# Load picture to an Image Active X excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i need some help the situation is that i have some code that put on a worksheet various Image active X and i need to seach the images from a folder path i thy this but says taht the file doest exit when i dloble check and the file is on the folder.

```
conter = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
inica = "C:\Mydocuments\folderpath\images\"
For i = 2 To conter
tope = Cells(i, "K").Top
izq = Cells(i, "K").Left
valor = Cells(i, "K").Value
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Image.1", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=izq, Top:=tope, Width:=160, Height _
    :=55).Select
fullpath = inica & valor & ".jpg"
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fullpath)`enter code here`
Next
```

i have a lot of image active X and i dont know how to add the image from everyone the name of the file i want to chheck is on th K column
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I added a message box which shows the path. Also it puts the new activex control into variable img so you can do that with multiple controls

```
dim img as variant

conter = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
inica = "C:\Mydocuments\folderpath\images\"
For i = 2 To conter
    tope = Cells(i, "K").Top
    izq = Cells(i, "K").Left
    valor = Cells(i, "K").Value

    set img = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Image.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=izq, Top:=tope, Width:=160, Height _
        :=55)
    fullpath = inica & valor & ".jpg"

    'This is for debugging
    msgbox fullpath

    img.Object.Picture = LoadPicture(fullpath)`enter code here`
Next
```

Comment: I tried to do that but i recieve an error '438' object doesnt support this property method

Comment: Ok. I fixed that. img.Object.Picture  See my edited answer